# How to integrate web app in App service Environment v2 with Azure Redis cache?

Tags: azure, redis, azure-web-app-service, ase

I am working on Creating a AppService Environment v2 in a VNet. And want app services in ASE to access a Azure Redis Cache (Basic Tier)that is already in use(with public DNS & not in a VNet). I have checked for Service endpoints in VNet but can’t find one for Redis.

I can’t migrate the Redis Cache into a VNet as that functionality only available for premium tier as Redis cache is already created.

Do I need to create/use a private endpoint or Is there any other way that I can do this?